# Scala 3: How do you extract the names of elements from a Mirror.Sum as a tuple?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-3

I'm trying to make a schema type that can allow you describe Scala types in a generic, fully-typed manner. I have product and coproduct versions of this, and now I'm trying to derive them using Scala 3's mirrors.

The particular challenge I am currently facing is to extract the element names from the `MirroredElemLabels` type within a `Mirror.` My understanding is that these types are singleton types and can be converted to their singleton values using `scala.compiletime.constValue.`

I can confirm that the `MirroredElemLabels` are what I am expected in the following test case:

```scala
sealed trait SuperT
final case class SubT1( int : Int ) extends SuperT
final case class SubT2( str : String ) extends SuperT

val mirror = summon[Mirror.SumOf[SuperT]]
summon[mirror.MirroredElemLabels =:= ("SubT1", "SubT2")]
```

I should be able to extract the values with the following type class:

```scala
import scala.deriving.Mirror
import scala.compiletime.constValue

trait NamesDeriver[ T ] {
    type Names <: Tuple

    def derive : Names
}

object NamesDeriver {
    type Aux[ T, Ns ] = NamesDeriver[ T ] { type Names = Ns }

    inline given mirDeriver[ T, ELs <: Tuple ](
        using
        mir : Mirror.Of[ T ] { type MirroredElemLabels = ELs },
        der : NamesDeriver[ ELs ],
    ) : NamesDeriver[ T ] with {
        type Names = der.Names

        def derive : der.Names = der.derive
    }

    given emptyDeriver : NamesDeriver[ EmptyTuple ] with {
        type Names = EmptyTuple
        def derive : EmptyTuple = EmptyTuple
    }

    inline given labelsDeriver[ N <: String & Singleton, Tail <: Tuple ](
        using
        next : NamesDeriver.Aux[ Tail, Tail ],
    ) : NamesDeriver[ N *: Tail ] with {
        type Names = N *: Tail

        def derive : N *: Tail = constValue[ N ] *: next.derive
    }

    def getNames[ T ](
        using
        nd : NamesDeriver[ T ],
    ) : nd.Names = nd.derive
}
```

But this will not compile:

```
not a constant type: labelsDeriver.this.N; cannot take constValue
```

Why can't I use `constValue` here?

### Update

I have seen several methods out there, including Mateusz Kubuszok's below, that use `inline` methods extract label values using either `constValue` or `ValueOf`. I have been able to make these work, (a) I need to be able to do so within a type class instance, and (b) I'm curious why my own approach doesn't work!

To be more clear about my use case, the schema type I've come up encodes the subtypes of a coproduct as a tuple of `Subtype[T, ST, N <: String & Singleton, S]`, where `T` is the supertype's type, `ST` is the subtype's type, `N` is the narrow type of the subtype's name, and `S` is the narrow type of the subtype's own schema. I'd like to be able to derive this tuple using `given` type class instances.

### Update 2

Thanks to Mateusz's suggestion, I have been able to get the following version to compile...

```scala
import scala.deriving.Mirror
import scala.util.NotGiven
import scala.compiletime.{constValue, erasedValue, summonAll, summonInline}

trait Deriver {
    type Derived

    def derive : Derived
}

trait MirrorNamesDeriver[ T ] extends Deriver { type Derived <: Tuple }

object MirrorNamesDeriver {
    type Aux[ T, Ns <: Tuple ] = MirrorNamesDeriver[ T ] {type Derived = Ns}

    //    def values(t: Tuple): Tuple = t match
    //        case (h: ValueOf[_]) *: t1 => h.value *: values(t1)
    //        case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple

    inline given mirDeriver[ T, ElemLabels <: Tuple, NDRes <: Tuple ](
        using
        mir: Mirror.SumOf[ T ] {type MirroredElemLabels = ElemLabels},
        nd: NamesDeriver.Aux[ ElemLabels, ElemLabels ],
    ): MirrorNamesDeriver.Aux[ T, ElemLabels ] = {
        new MirrorNamesDeriver[ T ] {
            type Derived = ElemLabels

            def derive: ElemLabels = nd.derive
        }
    }
}

trait NamesDeriver[ R ] extends Deriver

object NamesDeriver {
    type Aux[ R, D ] = NamesDeriver[ R ] { type Derived = D }

    inline given emptyDeriver : NamesDeriver[ EmptyTuple ] with {
        type Derived = EmptyTuple
        def derive : EmptyTuple = EmptyTuple
    }

    inline given labelsDeriver[ N <: (String & Singleton), Tail <: Tuple ](
        using
        next : NamesDeriver.Aux[ Tail, Tail ],
    ) : NamesDeriver.Aux[ N *: Tail, N *: Tail ] =  {
        val derivedValue = constValue[ N ] *: next.derive

        new NamesDeriver[ N *: Tail ] {
            type Derived = N *: Tail

            def derive : N *: Tail = derivedValue
        }

    }

    inline def getNames[ T ](
        using
        nd : MirrorNamesDeriver[ T ],
    ) : nd.Derived = nd.derive

}
```

However, the above fails the following test case:

```scala
 sealed trait SuperT
 final case class SubT1( int : Int ) extends SuperT
 final case class SubT2( str : String ) extends SuperT

 "NamesDeriver" should "derive names from a coproduct" in {
     val nms = NamesDeriver.getNames[ SuperT ]
     nms.size shouldBe 2
 }
```

If I add the following evidence to the `using` parameter list in `mirDeriver`: `ev : NotGiven[ ElemLabels =:= EmptyTuple ]`, I get the following compilation error:

```
But no implicit values were found that match type util.NotGiven[? <: Tuple =:= EmptyTuple].
```

This suggests that the `Mirror` has and empty tuple for `MirroredElemLabels`. But again, I was able to confirm for the same test case that I could summon a mirror whose `MirroredElemLabels` type is `("SubT1", "SubtT2")`. Not only that, but in the *same* compilation error that says there is no such `NotGiven` instance, it reports a given `Mirror` instance with:

```
         {
            MirroredElemTypes = (NamesDeriverTest.this.SubT1, 
              NamesDeriverTest.this.SubT2
            ); MirroredElemLabels = (("SubT1" : String), ("SubT2" : String))
         }
```

What is going on here?? The plot thickens...

Comment: You have to do this when you are deriving you type class with an `inline` macro. That means that you cannot create typeclass go to value level, and ask for compile-time reflection. Instead you could design your typeclass so that it could embed the knowledge about its sum/product elements when it is constructed (with an `inline`), and then on value level you would just call an instance of a typeclass. See here for an example https://github.com/MateuszKubuszok/dbg/blob/3d32b63211dd88a0b396b249aca2b1a8c6ea721f/src/main/scala/dbg/schema/Dbg.scala#L130

Comment: In other words you have to rewrite your `def getNames` to `inline` if you want to be able to use compile-time reflection and/or redesign `NamesDeriver` so that it would construct values in compile time and then return constants in these new instances.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do with `constValue`. `constValue["a"]` works, but `val a = "a"; constValue[a.type]` does not, which leads me to believe that _any_ sort of identifier will not be treated as a constant type by the compiler. I feels as though accessing the naming information through these types was meant for macros.

Comment: @MichaelZajac I have definitely seen working examples online using `constValue` to get element labels from a mirror, so I'm pretty sure it *can* work. See, e.g. https://blog.oyanglul.us/scala/dotty/en/generic-type-class-derivation

Comment: I think there is a bug, since I have been able to extract element labels from `Product` mirrors, but not `Sum`s. It looks like the compiler is not able to infer the `ElemLabels` parameter correctly in the latter case. I've reported the issue here: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/14150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out a workaround! Rather than parameterize the `Mirror`'s `MirroredElemLabels` type in order to include `NamesDeriver` as a second context parameter in `mirDeriver`, we can just use `summonInline` to conjure up the `NamesDeriver` within the inlined given definition:

```scala
    transparent inline given mirDeriver[ T ](
        using
        mir: Mirror.SumOf[ T ],
    ): MirrorNamesDeriver.Aux[ T, mir.MirroredElemLabels ] = {
        val namesDeriver = summonInline[ NamesDeriver.Aux[ mir.MirroredElemLabels, mir.MirroredElemLabels ] ]

        new MirrorNamesDeriver[ T ] {
            type Derived = mir.MirroredElemLabels

            def derive: mir.MirroredElemLabels = namesDeriver.derive
        }
    }
```

Adding `transparent` helps my IDE recognize the resulting type, but it doesn't seem to matter for compilation. Here's the results of the test case:

```scala
val deriver = summon[MirrorNamesDeriver[ SuperT ]]
summon[deriver.Derived =:= ("SubT1", "SubT2")]
val nms = MirrorNamesDeriver.getNames[ SuperT ]
println(nms.size)
```

...output:

```scala
val deriver: MirrorNamesDeriver[SuperT]{Derived = ("SubT1", "SubT2")} = anon$4@79d56038
val res0: ("SubT1", "SubT2") =:= ("SubT1", "SubT2") = generalized constraint
val nms: ("SubT1", "SubT2") = (SubT1,SubT2)
2
```

#### Update

It turns out it's possible to do this just using type classes summoned via context parameters. See https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/14150#issuecomment-998586254.

Answer (score 3):

When I needed this functionaliy I just wrote a utility to achieve this, which uses `ValueOf` (this is like `Witness` from Shapeless but build-in):

```
// T is m.MirroredElemLabels - tuple of singleton types describing labels
inline def summonLabels[T <: Tuple]: List[String] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple => Nil
    case _: (t *: ts)  => summonInline[ValueOf[t]].value.asInstanceOf[String] :: summonLabels[ts]
```

```
val labels  = summonLabels[p.MirroredElemLabels]
```

But you could probably implement it with less code using something like

```
// 1. turn type (A, B, ...) into type (ValueOf[A], ValueOf[B], ...)
//    (for MirroredElemLabels A, B, ... =:= String) 
// 2. for type (ValueOf[A], ValueOf[B], ...) summon List[ValueOf[A | B | ...]]
//    (which should be a List[ValueOf[String]] but if Scala
//     gets confused about this you can try `.asInstanceOf`)
// 3. turn it into a List[String]
summonAll[Tuple.Map[p.MirroredElemLabels, ValueOf]]
  .map(valueOf => valueOf.value.asInstanceOf[String])
```

EDIT:

Try to rewrite your code to

```
    inline given labelsDeriver[ N <: String & Singleton, Tail <: Tuple ](
        using
        next : NamesDeriver.Aux[ Tail, Tail ],
    ) : NamesDeriver[ N *: Tail ] =
      // makes sure value is computed before instance is constructed
      val precomputed = constValue[ N ] *: next.derive
      new NamesDeriver[ N *: Tail ] {
        type Names = N *: Tail

        // apparently, compiler thinks that you wanted to put
        // constValue resolution into new instance's method body
        // rather than within macro, which is why it fails
        // so try to force it to compute it in compile-time
        def derive : N *: Tail = precomputed
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Mateusz! In fact I have been able to retrieve element labels using this method, but I haven't been able do so in a type class such that I can use them to construct a tuple of schemas for each of the subtypes. When I have tried to use `using vo: ValueOf[ N ]` with an `inline given` instance it hasn't been able to find an implicit `ValueOf`! So it seems to be the same issue as I'm having with `constValue`

Comment: Thanks again @MateuszKubuszok! I'm now running into *another* issue, which is that when I construct a deriver this way, it doesn't appear able to find a `Mirror` instance with non-empty element labels. Any ideas about that?...

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to get the element labels is with `constValueTuple`. Here it is as a tuple of strings:

```
constValueTuple[mirror.MirroredElemLabels].map[[X] =>> String]([X] => (x: X) => "" + x)
```

Or if you just want it as a `List[String]`:

```
constValueTuple[mirror.MirroredElemLabels].productIterator.map(v => "" + v).toList
```